# "Обои на любой вкус"

Tags: употребление-слов

Встретил как-то подобное объявление. Честно говоря, читается как курьез - как предложение попробовать обои. Но, с другой стороны, понятно, что речь об эстетическом вкусе. И как быть с этим предложением? Можно и нужно ли его как-то перефразировать?
Заранее благодарю за варианты ответов

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, фраза нормальная. *Вкус* - многозначное слово, это не только свойство пищи, но и эстетическая оценка. Так можно придраться и к слову *обои* - как в анекдоте: не обои, а оба.

Сравните с действительно курьезными случаями: эта пища желудку по душе, из трубы лило как из ведра, кролики уходят своими корнями в далекую древность, этой подставке для цветов по плечу даже большие кадки...

Answer (score 1):

"Обои на все вкусы". Здесь нежелательных ассоциаций не возникает. 
Но учтите, что законы рекламы не всегда подчиняются эстетическим предпочтениям чопороных носителей языка. Вот заметили бы вы это объявление, будь оно составлено по правилам стилистики?

//----------------------------

> А почему "обои на любой вкус" лучше, чем "обои на все вкусы"?

Отнюдь. Хуже. Хуже тем, что вызвали нежелательную ассоциацию у топикстартера. Второй вариант их не вызывает, поскольку "(пищевой) вкус" как орган чувства множественного числа не имеет.
Можно спорить, насколько оправдана нежелательная ассоциация у читающего исходный вариант (у меня он тоже никаких ложных ассоциаций не вызывает), но пишущий таки должен иметь в виду "вкусы" всех читающих...

А вот с точки зрения рекламы "хуже" зачастую становится "лучше". Поскольку своей "хужестью" привлекает внимание. А для чего еще существует реклама?!

Comment: А  почему  "обои  на  любой  вкус"  лучше,  чем  "обои  на  все  вкусы"?

Comment: Ответил в тексте моего основного ответа.